# Query to get distinct count of column with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

I have a table name POEMS with columns poemID and userID. I want to make the poemID distinct and show only the count in the userID column. There are 3 poemID's with 1. I want to make it show poemID 1 and userID would be 2. poemID 2 and userID 3, for the 3 rows and poemID 3 with userID 1 for the 1 row.

```
|poemID | userID|
   1       1
   1       5
   2       2
   2       5
   2       4
   3       2
```

I want the above table to look like the table below.

```
|poemID | userID |
   1       2
   2       3
   3       1
```

My SQL query im trying is below but its not working. Please help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(poemID), COUNT(userID) FROM POEMS GROUP BY poemID;
```

Comment: you don't need `DISTINCT(poemID)`, just `poemID` should work.

Comment: `DISTINCT` isn't a function, it doesn't apply to a single column. It applies to the entire SELECT list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a straight aggregation query:

```
SELECT poemID, COUNT(*) no_users 
FROM POEMS 
GROUP BY poemID;
```

Or, if the same user may appear multiple times for a given poem and you want to count it only once:

```
SELECT poemID, COUNT(DISTINCT userID) no_distinct_users 
FROM POEMS 
GROUP BY poemID;
```

Comment: Wow you are fast. Thank you GMB!